# I am not able to run dask yarn cluster on AWS EMR

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dask, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, dask-distributed

I want run dask on EMR using YarnCluster.
I have used below bootstrap script but I have run these instructions in SSH console.

```
#!/bin/bash
HELP="Usage: bootstrap-dask [OPTIONS]

Example AWS EMR Bootstrap Action to install and configure Dask and Jupyter

By default it does the following things:
- Installs miniconda
- Installs dask, distributed, dask-yarn, pyarrow, and s3fs. This list can be
  extended using the --conda-packages flag below.
- Packages this environment for distribution to the workers.
- Installs and starts a jupyter notebook server running on port 8888. This can
  be disabled with the --no-jupyter flag below.

Options:
    --jupyter / --no-jupyter    Whether to also install and start a Jupyter
                                Notebook Server. Default is True.
    --password, -pw             Set the password for the Jupyter Notebook
                                Server. Default is 'dask-user'.
    --conda-packages            Extra packages to install from conda.
"

# Parse Inputs. This is specific to this script, and can be ignored
# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Check if running on the master node. If not, there's nothing do.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
grep -q '"isMaster": true' /mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json \
|| { echo "Not running on master node, nothing to do" && exit 0; }


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 2. Install Miniconda
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Installing Miniconda"
curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh
bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
rm /tmp/miniconda.sh
echo -e '\nexport PATH=$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
conda update conda -y

# configure conda environment
#source ~/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
#conda activate base

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3. Install packages to use in packaged environment
#
# We install a few packages by default, and allow users to extend this list
# with a CLI flag:
#
# - dask-yarn >= 0.7.0, for deploying Dask on YARN.
# - pyarrow for working with hdfs, parquet, ORC, etc...
# - s3fs for access to s3
# - conda-pack for packaging the environment for distribution
# - ensure tornado 5, since tornado 6 doesn't work with jupyter-server-proxy
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Installing base packages"
conda install \
-c conda-forge \
-y \
-q \
dask-yarn \
s3fs \
conda-pack \
tornado 

pip3 install pyarrow

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 4. Package the environment to be distributed to worker nodes
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Packaging environment"
conda pack -q -o $HOME/environment.tar.gz


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 5. List all packages in the worker environment
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Packages installed in the worker environment:"
conda list


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 6. Configure Dask
#
# This isn't necessary, but for this particular bootstrap script it will make a
# few things easier:
#
# - Configure the cluster's dashboard link to show the proxied version through
#   jupyter-server-proxy. This allows access to the dashboard with only an ssh
#   tunnel to the notebook.
#
# - Specify the pre-packaged python environment, so users don't have to
#
# - Set the default deploy-mode to local, so the dashboard proxying works
#
# - Specify the location of the native libhdfs library so pyarrow can find it
#   on the workers and the client (if submitting applications).
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Configuring Dask"
mkdir -p $HOME/.config/dask
cat <<EOT >> $HOME/.config/dask/config.yaml
distributed:
  dashboard:
    link: "/proxy/{port}/status"

yarn:
  environment: /home/hadoop/environment.tar.gz
  deploy-mode: local

  worker:
    env:
      ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/

  client:
    env:
      ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/
EOT
# Also set ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR in ~/.bashrc so it's set for the local user
echo -e '\nexport ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native' >> $HOME/.bashrc




# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 8. Install jupyter notebook server and dependencies
#
# We do this after packaging the worker environments to keep the tar.gz as
# small as possible.
#
# We install the following packages:
#
# - notebook: the Jupyter Notebook Server
# - ipywidgets: used to provide an interactive UI for the YarnCluster objects
# - jupyter-server-proxy: used to proxy the dask dashboard through the notebook server
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo "Installing Jupyter"
    conda install \
    -c conda-forge \
    -y \
    -q \
    notebook \
    ipywidgets \
    jupyter-server-proxy \
    jupyter


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 9. List all packages in the client environment
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Packages installed in the client environment:"
conda list


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 10. Configure Jupyter Notebook
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Configuring Jupyter"
mkdir -p $HOME/.jupyter
JUPYTER_PASSWORD="dask-user"
HASHED_PASSWORD=`python -c "from notebook.auth import passwd; print(passwd('$JUPYTER_PASSWORD'))"`
cat <<EOF >> $HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
c.NotebookApp.password = u'$HASHED_PASSWORD'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
EOF


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 11. Define an upstart service for the Jupyter Notebook Server
#
# This sets the notebook server up to properly run as a background service.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Configuring Jupyter Notebook Upstart Service"
cat <<EOF > /tmp/jupyter-notebook.service
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Notebook
[Service]
ExecStart=$HOME/miniconda/bin/jupyter-notebook --allow-root --config=$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/jupyter.pid
WorkingDirectory=$HOME
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
sudo mv /tmp/jupyter-notebook.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl enable jupyter-notebook.service


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 12. Start the Jupyter Notebook Server
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Starting Jupyter Notebook Server"
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart jupyter-notebook.service

#$HOME/miniconda/bin/jupyter-notebook --allow-root --config=$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

after this i start jupyter notebook using `$HOME/miniconda/bin/jupyter-notebook --allow-root --config=$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`
jupyter notebook start successfully.
When i run this code on notebook

```
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster
from dask.distributed import Client

# Create a cluster
cluster = YarnCluster()

# Connect to the cluster
client = Client(cluster)
```

it gives error like

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 client = Client(cluster)

File ~/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/client.py:835, in Client.__init__(self, address, loop, timeout, set_as_default, scheduler_file, security, asynchronous, name, heartbeat_interval, serializers, deserializers, extensions, direct_to_workers, connection_limit, **kwargs)
    832 elif isinstance(getattr(address, "scheduler_address", None), str):
    833     # It's a LocalCluster or LocalCluster-compatible object
    834     self.cluster = address
--> 835     status = getattr(self.cluster, "status")
    836     if status and status in [Status.closed, Status.closing]:
    837         raise RuntimeError(
    838             f"Trying to connect to an already closed or closing Cluster {self.cluster}."
    839         )

AttributeError: 'YarnCluster' object has no attribute 'status'
```

Also when I use LocalCluster instead of YarnCluster it run perfectly. I am stuck here for days please help. Also how we configure worker nodes.

Comment: Interesting, which version of dask and distributed are you using?

Comment: No one will go through that long bash bootstrap script. Either it is not part of the problem (but you have some sort of version conflict locally), or you need to boil things down a huge amount.

Comment: i am using dask and distributed version : 2022.6.0

Comment: also when i use client = Client('tcp://10.0.1.**:42047') it works fine

Comment: client = Client(cluster.scheduler_address)